# Validating a CheckBox field - ASP.NET and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to make a simple validation
on some agreements by checking an asp:checkbox
and clicking an asp:button.

On my Button I am calling this:

OnClientClick="ValidateConditions();"

And the function runs by this:

```
function ValidateConditions() {
 if ($('#ChkAccept').is(':checked')) {
             alert("Checked");
                  args.IsValid = true;
               }
                else {
                   alert('Nope it is not checked');
                args.IsValid = false;
           }
         }
```

It works so far, but how do I stop running my button method when
args.IsValid = false; ? Right now it shows the message and
runs the method in both cases.

It must be a simple thing that I need..
Best regards.

Comment: Any progress with the new code?

Answer (score 1):

do the below to prevent the event of the button :--
but do also OnClientClick="return ValidateConditions(this); in your markup code

```
 function ValidateConditions(element,e) {
    if ($(element).prop('checked')) {
        alert("Checked");
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Nope it is not checked');
        args.IsValid = false;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
return false ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I an trying your code, but still it runs my server side click handler:

   Protected Sub BtnConfirm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnConfirm.Click
'Code that runs
End Sub

Comment: please make sure you write the correct call to the function ( OnClientClick="return ValidateConditions(this,event);

Answer (score 0):

Removed all other javascripts:

Just use:

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkAccept" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="I accept the conditions" /> 
    <br />
   <asp:Button ID="BtnConfirm" runat="server" CssClass="uniBtn" Text="Send"
   OnClientClick="if(! $( '#ChkAccept' ).prop( 'checked' )){alert('Not Ticked');return false;}" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying your solution, but in this case it says "Nope it is not checked" in both cases, and it continues to run the code behind.

Comment: Hi, nope, it just shows the message and then runs my button click handler:

Protected Sub BtnConfirm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnConfirm.Click 
'Code that runs 
End Sub

Comment: It's just simple: <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkAccept" runat="server" Text="Please accept the conditions" />

Comment: Hi, it's still running the code. I have made a small example for download here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17202645/test.aspx.zip

Comment: Now my method only runs when the checkbox is ticked! Nice. Now I just need the alert to show up if it is not checked.

Comment: Superb - now it works. Is the ClientIDMode="Static" property on the checkbox doing the trick??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
OnClientClick="return ValidateConditions(this);"
```

and

```
function ValidateConditions(checkbox) {
    return $(checkbox).is(':checked');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying your solution. Nothing happens when I clicking the button, both when the checkbox is checeked and unchecked. But at least it doesn't run my code behind.